# Python scraping deep nested divs whose classes change

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm somewhat new to python, and working on this 1st part of a project where i need to get the link(s) on a FanDuel page, and i've been spinning my tires trying get the 'href'.

Here's what the Inspect Element shows: 
[image: what i'm trying to get to is highlighted]

What i'm trying to get to is highlighted above.

I see that the  seems to be the parent, but as you go down the tree, the classes listed with lettering (ie - "_a _ch _al _nr _dq _ns _nt _nu") changes from day to day.

What I noticed is that the 'href' that i need has a constant "data-test-id" that does not change, so i was trying to use that as my way to find what i need, but it does not seem to be working.

I'm not sure how far, or if, I need to drill down farther to get what I need, or if my code is totally off. Thanks for your help in advance!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.fanduel.com/contests/mlb/96"

#authentication might not be necessary, it was a test, still getting the same results
site = requests.get(url, cookies={'X-Auth-Token':'MY TOKEN IS HERE'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'lxml')

game = soup.find_all('a', {'data-test-id':"ContestCardEnterLink"})

#If i use this, i get an error
game = soup.find_all('a', {'data-test-id':"ContestCardEnterLink"})[('href')]


print(game)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML is constructed by javascript, to check this, instead of using inspect element, use view source-page and see if the HTML is already constructed there ( this is the html that you get when you do requests.get() ) ,i've already checked this and this is true. To resolve this, you should have to use Selenium to render the javascript on the page, and then you can get the source page code by selenium after he constructed the elements from DOM.